# How "rm" command in Linux works?

Tags: linux, file, command

I want to know how the `rm` command works in Linux. What system calls does it invoke? Which file operations are used to execute this command?

Sorry if my question looks trivial, but I'm new to Linux file systems.

Answer (score 3):

Questions like this should be easily be answerable by [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

```
$ touch test
$ strace rm test
execve("/usr/bin/rm", ["rm", "test"], [/* 26 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xb86000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabf8423000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=45618, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 45618, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabf8417000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107760, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabf7e42000
mprotect(0x7fabf7ff8000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fabf81f8000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7fabf81f8000
mmap(0x7fabf81fe000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabf81fe000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabf8416000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabf8414000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fabf8414740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fabf81f8000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fabf8424000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fabf8417000, 45618)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xb86000
brk(0xba7000)                           = 0xba7000
brk(0)                                  = 0xba7000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106065056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106065056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fabf191b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2502, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fabf8422000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2502
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fabf8422000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "test", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 7026
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "test", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "test", W_OK)       = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "test", 0)           = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The decisive call in my case is `unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "test", 0)` but the specifics probably depend on the system architecture and `rm` version.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the source code here:

- http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/rm.c

The actual removing of the files happen in:

- http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/remove.c

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on ignacio's answer [`unlink(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/unlink.2) is the primary system call that it will make to actually remove files, and [`rmdir(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/rmdir.2) to remove directories, but there are other system calls that it makes as well including:

- [`open(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/open.2)
- [`fstat(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/stat.2)
- [`lstat(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/stat.2)
- [`rmdir(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/rmdir.2)
- [`fstatfs(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/statfs.2)
- [`unlink(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/unlink.2)
- [`malloc(3)`](http://mdoc.su/o/malloc.3)
- [`free(3)`](http://mdoc.su/o/malloc.3)
- [`write(2)`](http://mdoc.su/o/write.2)
- [`fflush(3)`](http://mdoc.su/o/fflush.3)

For the complete source of the implementation in OpenBSD see http://bxr.su/openbsd/bin/rm/rm.c

Answer (score 1):

The `rm` command is provided by [coreutils](https://github.com/goj/coreutils/). `rm.c` is the source for the *driver* program. `remove.c` does the actual work. In particular, `excise` is what you're looking for:

```
/* Remove the file system object specified by ENT.  IS_DIR specifies
   whether it is expected to be a directory or non-directory.
   Return RM_OK upon success, else RM_ERROR.  */
static enum RM_status
excise (FTS *fts, FTSENT *ent, struct rm_options const *x, bool is_dir)
{
  int flag = is_dir ? AT_REMOVEDIR : 0;
  if (unlinkat (fts->fts_cwd_fd, ent->fts_accpath, flag) == 0)
    {
      if (x->verbose)
        {
          printf ((is_dir
                   ? _("removed directory: %s\n")
                   : _("removed %s\n")), quote (ent->fts_path));
        }
      return RM_OK;
    }

  /* The unlinkat from kernels like linux-2.6.32 reports EROFS even for
     nonexistent files.  When the file is indeed missing, map that to ENOENT,
     so that rm -f ignores it, as required.  Even without -f, this is useful
     because it makes rm print the more precise diagnostic.  */
  if (errno == EROFS)
    {
      struct stat st;
      if ( ! (lstatat (fts->fts_cwd_fd, ent->fts_accpath, &st)
                       && errno == ENOENT))
        errno = EROFS;
    }

  if (ignorable_missing (x, errno))
    return RM_OK;

  /* When failing to rmdir an unreadable directory, the typical
     errno value is EISDIR, but that is not as useful to the user
     as the errno value from the failed open (probably EPERM).
     Use the earlier, more descriptive errno value.  */
  if (ent->fts_info == FTS_DNR)
    errno = ent->fts_errno;
  error (0, errno, _("cannot remove %s"), quote (ent->fts_path));
  mark_ancestor_dirs (ent);
  return RM_ERROR;
}
```

As you can see, it uses the `unlinkat` syscall.

Answer (score 0):

It invokes [`unlink(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) to remove the filesystem object. Whatever happens from there is delegated to the filesystem driver.

Answer (score 0):

As you possbily know, `rm` tool is open source and it is part of `core-utils` package. Henceforth, you can read the implementation of `rm`, for example, on [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/rm.c) or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html).